# Why "по одному часу" is in dative while "по два часа" is not?

Tags: грамматика, числительные, дательный-падеж, винительный-падеж

I understand why the dative is used in this sentence, given the presence of the preposition **по**

*"Я спала два раза по **одному часу**"*

but I don't understand why it's **not** used in the following

*"Я спала два раза по **два часа**"*

I have become accustomed to speaking that way so it is not an issue in daily life, but I would like to know what the rule is that guides this apparent inconsistency, assuming there *is* such a rule. I struggled to even describe the problem, so if there is a more appropriate title please don't hesitate to edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `один`, `тысяча`, `миллион`, `триллион` (in other words, with all that numeral that can be combined with `один`) dative is used - is just a rule that should be memorized.

So:

> По [одному] миллиону долларов попросили оба министерства

but

> Министерства запросили по два миллиона.

Relevant quote from slightly outdated yet quite famous [grammar reference](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/59.htm):

> Предлог по в так называемом дистрибутивном (распределительном)
>   значении управляет дательным и винительным падежом числительного. Ср.:
>
> по одному рублю, по тысяче книг, по миллиону жителей, по
>   миллиарду рублей (при числительных один, тысяча, миллион, миллиард);

The other case when we need dative is when we used quantitative words like `много`, `несколько` like in `по многу раз` or `по нескольку раз`.

Comment: So it's literally just a rule? I am of course willing to accept that, I've just been confused because I've never seen it addressed / written down anywhere. Well that's easy enough - thanks!

Comment: @AudreyM well, native speakers just using some forms without even thinking what case they are using but as of rules, yes it is actually just a rule - I've added a reference to the answer.